# How randomness is when initializing the c/c++ seed with small values and a higher one?

Tags: c++, random-seed

I am using srand() in order to have some pseudo-randomness in my c/c++ program.

I was wondering about whether a srand(1) and srand(2) have a randomness much like, lets say, srand(21254) and srand(9897455)?

Because, I was running my program with small different numbers for the seed, and I have an impression that is unlike!

Best Regards

Comment: Suggest you investigate the new functions in `<random>` see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random  especially `mt19937`  With regard to `rand()`: _"There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence produced"_ http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand

Comment: You should not use `srand` with a constant number. Your program will give the same sequence with each start.

Comment: Unrelated to your question (well, to your possible problem anyway) but I suggest you start using the new [pseudo-random number generation classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) in C++.

Comment: @mch That might actually be fine in some situations, for example for testing to get a predictable result.

Comment: This is going to rely on the implementation.  The standard requires very little as far as `srand`/`rand` go.

Comment: I have found that Microsoft's `rand` in particular has a lot of correlation between the seed and the first one or two random numbers. If you're stuck using it, throw away some random numbers to get better behavior.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, can you please check the link you gave?

Comment: I'll just leave this here : [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestions, I'm using a solver which uses srand48(), so changing it is not option. Is it harmful?

Comment: srand48() could imply that it's using a 48 bit seed. Most implementations of rand() use something like a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), which will cycle through every possible value one time before repeating. If this version of rand uses a 48 bit seed, you'd have to call rand() 281,474,976,710,656 (281 trillion) times before it repeats assuming it's similar to typical implementations of rand.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments say, you should be using a real random number library if you are concerned about the quality of random numbers.

`srand()` and `rand()` are *usually* a basic periodic pseudorandom number generator. There will be a fixed sequence of values that cycle, all in a row. If you received 12 as your last number, and receive 600 as your next number, then the next time the cycle rolls back around to 12 you will again receive 600 as your next number.

Therefore, the seed does not affect the "randomness" or quality of the pseudorandom numbers. Calling `srand(21254)` or `srand(9897455)` simply starts at different points in the same sequence.

Note: it is possible that a particular implementation of `rand()` will *not* use this method: however, it is unlikely and in the absence of any guarantees you are better off with the [`<random>` library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) which *does* have guarantees about the methods used to generate random numbers. The classes in that library will produce better quality sequences of random numbers.

Comment: I'm using a library/solver which calls srand48(), I will check if it has the same implementation. On the other hand, the point of my question is that if we use srand(1) and we suppose that it will generate 12 as starting point and 600 as the next value, does srand with close value of seed (2,3,4,..) will result in close behaviour, like 14 as first point and 650 the next one! It's different, but they share a common pattern!

Answer (score 0):

You say in the comments that you don't have the option of choosing a better random number generator. That is a shame, because C++ has [the `random` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) since C++11, and it's vastly improved over the old `rand`/`srand`.

There's definitely a correlation between the seed you use in `srand` and the resulting numbers that you pull from `rand`, that's the whole point of seeding. Some C++ implementations will make this more obvious than others, since the implementation of `rand` isn't tightly specified and is left to each library.

The simplest way to hide this correlation is to take a few random numbers after seeding and simply throw them away, because the correlation becomes less obvious with each generated number. If it didn't, it wouldn't be an acceptable random number generator.

```
srand(1);
cout << "throwing away " << rand() << endl;
cout << "throwing away " << rand() << endl;
cout << "using " << rand() << endl;

srand(2);
cout << "throwing away " << rand() << endl;
cout << "throwing away " << rand() << endl;
cout << "using " << rand() << endl;
```